# What did Arjun see in the Vishwaroop of lord Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

What is the need of lord Krishna showing his  Vishwaroop to Arjun?

What did Arjun see in the Vishwaroop? Did anyone else in the battle could see it?

How many times lord Krishna shown his Vishwaroop in Mahabharat?

Comment: _"What is the need of lord Krishna showing his Vishwaroop to Arjun?"_ There wasn't any need and nor Krishna showed it by his own wish. It was Arjuna who wanted to see. He asked to Krishna, I want to see your all incarnations at same time. I want to see who actually you are. If you are pleased with my devotion then kindly show me your true self.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What is the need of lord Krishna showing his Vishwaroop to Arjun?**

Because Arjuna requested so,

> मन्यसे यदि तच्छक्यं मया द्रष्टुमिति प्रभो।
>
> योगेश्वर ततो मे त्वं दर्शयाऽत्मानमव्ययम्।।11.4।।

*O Master ! If you think that it is possible for me to see that form, then, O Lord of the Yogins, please show me Your Immortal Self.*

**What did Arjun see in the Vishwaroop?**

Entire Universe.

> इहैकस्थं जगत्कृत्स्नं पश्याद्य सचराचरम्।
>
> मम देहे गुडाकेश यच्चान्यद्द्रष्टुमिच्छसि।।11.7।।

*Now, behold the entire universe, including the moving and the unmoving, and whatsoever else you desire to see-all established in one here, in My body, O Gudakesa (Arjuna) !*

**Note:** Please read chapter 11 of Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta for more details.

**Did anyone else in the battle could see it?**

Not in battle but other than Arjuna, **Sanjaya** and **Barbareek** must have seen Vishwaroop as they were blessed with Divya Drishti and watching the all incidents of the Mahabharata war. Sanjaya narrated the Vishwaroop to Dhritrastra.

> 'This Sanjaya, O king, will describe the battle to thee. **Nothing in the whole battle will be beyond this one's eyes**.'  - [Source](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06002.htm)

**Lord Hanuman** also must have seen as he was present at the chariot of **Arjuna**. Other than them, great sages like Krishna Dvaipāyana (Vedavyasa) and heavenly bodies also might have seen from their Divine powers.

**How many times lord Krishna shown his Vishwaroop in Mahabharat?**

- When Lord Shri Krishna visited the court of Hastinapura as the peace messenger. - [Source](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05131.htm)
- When Lord Shri Krishna gave the divine knowledge of Bhagavad Gita to Arjuna. - as described in the above part of this question
- When Lord Shri Krishna met Utanka after the Mahabharata battle. - [Source](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14055.htm)

Comment: Apart from Arjuna, Sanjaya and Barbareek, Hanuman also was the one who saw Vishvaroop of Lord. And he also heard whole Geeta updesha(with Arjuna) from Krishna. Hanuman was present at chariot of Arjuna in invisible form because Krishna ordered Hanuman to stay on chariot of Pandvas and protect them.

Comment: Just to help you, Krishna has shown his vishvaroop 2 times. One time He showed on request of Arjuna before begining of Mahaabharat war. Second time he showed after war. When war got over and Yuddhishtir became king and all got normal then Krishna went for Dwarika. During his Journey he met great sage (whose name I forgot). And he also requested Krishna to show his Vishvaroop and Krishna showed his Vishvaroop to him. You can search regarding this incident to find valid reference. Heard this story long ago.

Comment: How can you say that sanjaya saw universal form? @rishabh

Comment: @KrishnShweta Because Great sage Ved Vyasa gave divya drishti to Sanjay so he can narrate every incident of Mahabharat war to Dhritrashtra.

Comment: @KrishnShweta Yes, Sanjaya saw Vishvroopa...Please read Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta 11.9

Comment: @rishabh and YDS, please see the verse 11.10. It says "arjuna saw the universal form..." And sanjaya had vision to see past, present and future ( about future i don't know) but not the vision to see Almighty God. And whatever sanjaya described about the universal form is what arjuna said while seeing Krishna.

Comment: @KrishnShweta if u hv strong compilation after reading entire Mahabharata and not only few shlokas then pls feel free to edit my answer..

Comment: I know only this section of MB http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06013.htm  from this u can conclude that sanjaya wasn't giving live telecast but after bishma was defeated @yds

Comment: @KrishnShweta You would like to read http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06002.htm Sanjaya got Divya Drishti to see everything.. updated my answer too...